# How to get two distinct max value from this table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL problem.
I have a table like this one

```
USER            DATE              OP. TYPE
----   -----------------------  -----------
user1  2020-05-04 12:00:00.000       1
user2  2020-05-03 4:00:00.000        1
user1  2020-05-04 3:00:00.000        2
user3  2020-05-02 9:00:00.000        1
user3  2020-05-01 8:00:00.000        1
```

Every user can make two type of operations (1 or 2), and the system save in this table the operation  type and the datetime when the operation is executed.

I need to retrive from this table the last DateTime (the MAX value) of every type of operation, distinct for every user.
This should be the OUTPUT:

```
USER         DATE OP. 1               DATE OP. 2
----   -----------------------  ----------------------
user1  2020-05-04 12:00:00.000  2020-05-04 3:00:00.000
user2  2020-05-03 4:00:00.000   NULL
user3  2020-05-02 9:00:00.000   NULL
```

How can I achive this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a conditional `MAX`:

```sql
SELECT [User], --USER is a reserved keyword, and should not be used for object names
       MAX(CASE OpType WHEN 1 THEN [Date] END) AS Date1,
       MAX(CASE OpType WHEN 2 THEN [Date] END) AS Date2
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY [User];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [User]
      ,MAX(IIF([OP. TYPE] = 1, [Date], NULL))
      ,MAX(IIF([OP. TYPE] = 2, [Date], NULL))
FROM users 
GROUP BY [User];
```

Answer (score 0):

This matches the expected output.

```
select [USER], 
       max(case when [OP. TYPE]=1 then [DATE] else null end) as [DATE OP. 1],
       max(case when [OP. TYPE]=2 then [DATE] else null end) as [DATE OP. 2]
from UserOperations
group by [USER];
```